# Is there P in japanese

Tags: words

I have been wondering if Japanese language include letter P.
I have actually seen words like Pan in Japanese which means bread, but then I found out it was borrowed from Spanish.
Then is there any Japanese words (not borrowed from other languages) or verbs has letter P?

Sorry for my English, am still learning...

Comment: 日本 ＝「にっ**ぽ**ん」。。。

Comment: Nihon? well, I think it is also pronounced Nippon
thanks for your try
But is there words with one P
not like: Nippon, Yappari....

Comment: Heh.. then how about 「乾杯」「返品」「たんぽぽ」「もんぺ」「ち○ぽ」・・・(ん？「ん」の後ばっかりだ！)

Comment: @Achmad ぱくる, ぴかいち, ぺけ, ぽか, ぽいすて...

Comment: @choco Is it OK to include Chino-Japanese words?

Comment: ^ dunno! but たんぽぽ, もんぺ and ち○ぽ are not Sino-Japanese words, right?

Comment: Depending on theories, it could be.

Comment: You wrote "letter P", but it seems like you might actually be asking about the *sound* /p/.  Japanese isn't typically written with letters, so it doesn't really have a "letter P", but we can still talk about where /p/ occurs in different strata of vocabulary (non-mimetic native Japanese words, mimetic words, Sino-Japanese words, and recent loanwords).  Is that what you're really asking about?

Comment: It seems quite difficult to come up with words where the /p/ sound is not mimetic/onomatopoeic, not a loanword, and not caused by *rendaku* or *sokuon*.

Comment: @Earthliŋ It's not *rendaku*, which would give us /b/ instead, but yes, /p/ does occur after the moraic nasal under certain circumstances.  Rather than mention *rendaku*, you can talk about the special segments /Q/ and /N/.

Comment: @snailboat Is there a name for /h/ → /p/ after /ɴ/? (Like せん**ぱ**い、しん**ぴ**ん、おん**ぷ**、はん**ぺ**ん、さん**ぽ**).

Comment: @Earthliŋ Well, you can call it the /h/ 〜 /p/ alternation, but I understand if that's not a satisfying name :-)  It's a different process than *rendaku*, though.  Historically /p/ and /b/ were the pair related by *rendaku*, but /p/ became /h/ in intervocalic contexts, so now /h/ becomes /b/ via *rendaku*  – even though /b/ is of course not the voiced version of /h/!  For example, /hitobito/ or /hibi/, not \*/hitopito/ or \*/hipi/. You can find a description of the alternation between /h/ and /p/ in Labrune's *The Phonology of Japanese*.

Answer (score 1):

How about [せんぱい](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%85%88%E8%BC%A9)?

> Noun
>   1. senior (at work or school); superior; elder; older graduate; progenitor; old-timer

Comment: 「サッポロ」, along with so many place names in Hokkaido, comes from Ainu, not Japanese.  We can't let the kanji fool us.

Comment: @l'électeur Thanks for letting me know - I've removed that part of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

- へたっぴ、いいだしっぺ　← 屁
- …っぽい　← 多し

These words seem to be originally Japanese, besides onomatopoeia.

Answer (score 0):

Along time ago, there were originally no "h" sounds and were "P" sounds so in outdated kanji, you'd find a lot of onyomi and kunyomi with "P" sounds.