# /h/ sound changing in some Japanese counters

Tags: pronunciation, counters

I just noticed that the quantifying words that have an initial sound as /h/ such as 本、匹、分

For example: 本 hon
/h/ becomes /p/ : 1,6,8,10
/h/ becomes /b/ : 3,?? and ん sound before /b/ becomes /m/ (is it assimilation?)

1 [一本]{いっぽん}  ippon
2 [二本]{にほん}  nihon
3 [三本]{さんぼん} sanbon
4 [四本]{よんほん} yonhon
5 [五本]{ごほん} gohon
6 [六本]{ろっぽん} roppon
7 [七本]{ななほん} nanahon
8 [八本]{はっぽん} happon
9 [九本]{きゅうほん} kyuuhon
10 [十本]{じゅっぽん} juppon
？？ [何本]{なんぼん} nanbon

some words have sound  changing but other words, that have similar characteristics, do not.

For instance
"さんぼん" ; /h/---->/ b/
But
"よんほん"
sound does not change

I would like to know that
1. "Is there phonological explanation that can explain about changing of these sound?"
2. "why doesn't it occur in every words which have similar characteristics?"

Thank you for taking your time to answer my question!

Answer (score 5):

> *1. "Is there phonological explanation that can explain about changing of these sound?"*

If you are asking about the general rule, for *h* → *b*, it's 連濁 (rendaku) "compound voicing", in case you don't know. There is [a great answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/2526/7810) with [a dedicate tag](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rendaku) on this site, as well as [an independent article on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendaku).

For *h* → *p* thing, it's called 促音便 (sokuonbin), or would be like "gemination sandhi" in English. This is also a basic grammar of Japanese, [the usage](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/40325/7810) and [the history](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/60962/7810) already covered on this site. Also [a small patch of explanation on WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_phonology#Gemination_2).

Edit: I've found [an answer conveniently explains both](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38728/7810).

> *2. "why doesn't it occur in every words which have similar characteristics?"*

While you can simply call it irregularity, but it does have something behind the story.

If you take a look at a grammar book 『口語法』 compiled by a government commission in 1916, they have listed [漢語の数詞](http://dl.ndl.go.jp/info:ndljp/pid/1870063/29) (Sino-Japanese numerals):

> 一　二　三　四　五　六　七　八　九　十...

They did not provide any pronunciation in this section, but [an interesting note](http://dl.ndl.go.jp/info:ndljp/pid/926955/38) was put on this paragraph.

> 數を呼ぶに、次のように云ふことがある。聞きちがわせぬ爲である。
>   *Sometimes numbers are pronounced as follows, in order to avoid mishearing.*
>   二百四十番【ふたひやくよんじうばん】　四百七十九圓【よんひやくななじうきうえん】

From above, we can assume that the typical pronunciation of numbers at that time was:

> いち　に　さん　し　ご　ろく　しち　はち　く　じゅう

And **よん**・**なな**・**きゅう** that we have today were merely telephone pronunciation such as "tree", "fife", and "niner". Therefore, **よん**ほん was originally the ad hoc replacement of **し**ほん, which would have no condition to trigger rendaku.

Below are bonus tips about counter readings related to your question:

- ふた for 2 is the only one that has not gained wide acceptance, but still used as telephone pronunciation among pilots, traders, military etc. alongside ひと for 1.
- **はっ**ぽん and **はち**ほん are equally good. **なな**ほん can be read **しち**ほん as well. However, 7 has no *しっ- form, presumably because it'd be too confusing with 4 (し-) and 10 (じっ-; prescriptive form of じゅっ-).
- Numbers end with ん (3, 何, 万...) that make the counter voiced, such as さん**ぼ**ん, are rather exceptional that only found with some counters established in old times. さんがい (< 階 floors), なんびき (< 匹 animals) and いちまんべん (< 遍 rounds; repeats) are only others I can recall. Otherwise unvoiced counters remain unvoiced: なんかい (< 回 times), なん**ぴ**ん (< 品 pieces of work) etc.
- Foreign words as counters are never affected by rendaku, not even *h* → *p*: さんハロン (three furlongs), ろくヘクタール (six hectares), じゅっフォルダ (ten (computer) folders of...) etc.

Answer (score 3):

According to [いっぽん、にほん、さんぼん問題の解決](https://marginaliae.wordpress.com/2013/03/05/%E3%81%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%BD%E3%82%93%E3%80%81%E3%81%AB%E3%81%BB%E3%82%93%E3%80%81%E3%81%95%E3%82%93%E3%81%BC%E3%82%93%E5%95%8F%E9%A1%8C%E3%81%AE%E8%A7%A3%E6%B1%BA/), I adopt the author's theory and I translated it.

> 1. いっぽん　原形「ぽん」が前接する「いち」の語末母音脱落、促音便化によって保存された　***Due to the [apocope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocope) and [gemination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemination) of 「いち」, the original form of 「ぽん」has remained.***
> 2. にほん　母音間に挟まれたという条件下で、唇音退化が進行し「ほん」に結実 ***surrounded by vowels, labial weakening had proceed into 「ほん」.***
> 3. さんぼん　発音の音色については遡行同化、「ぼん」の有声化については順行同化が起こった
> 4. よんほん　和語「よ」が数詞整備によって「よん」となり「し」に代わって、成立済みの「ほん」に後代に接ぎ木された ***Wago「よ」became 「よん」by the adjustment of numeral. And, replacing 「し」and grafted to the 「ほん」later.***
> 5. ごほん　母音間に挟まれたという条件下で、唇音退化が進行し「ほん」に結実 ***surrounded by vowels, labial weakening had proceed into 「ほん」.***
> 6. ろっぽん　原形「ぽん」が前接する「ろく」の語末母音脱落、促音便化によって保存された ***Due to the apocope and gemination of 「ろく」, the original form of 「ぽん」has remained.***
> 7. ななほん　和語「なな」が数詞整備をへて「しち」と交替し、成立済みの「ほん」に後代に接ぎ木された
>      ***Wago「なな」switched into「しち」by the adjustment of numeral. And,  grafted to the 「ほん」later.***
> 8. はっぽん　原形「ぽん」が前接する「はち」の語末母音脱落、促音便化によって保存された ***Due to the apocope and gemination of 「はち」, the original form of 「ぽん」has remained.***
> 9. きゅうほん　母音間に挟まれたという条件下で、唇音退化が進行し「ほん」に結実。ただし「きゅう」の語形は後発 ***surrounded by vowels, labial weakening had proceed into 「ほん」.***
> 10. じっぽん　中古音の閉音節入声の日本語における表現形として促音が用いられ、これが原形「ぽん」を保存して接続した ***Closed syllable [checked tone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checked_tone) from Ancient Chinese phonology had expressed as gemination in Japanese. Thus, it preserved「ぽん」.***

---

> 通説として上代以前、古代日本語のハ行はパ行ないしファ行のような音であったとされている。まずスタート地点はパ行、**すなわち「『本』の原形は『ポン』であった」**

The author explains, in ancient times,it believed that the sound of ha-gyō of classical Japanese was pa-gyō or fa-gyō. i.e. original form of 本{ほん}(ほん) is 本{ぽん}(ぽん).

**For, 2 and 5. 二本{にほん}, 五本{ごほん}.**

> 数詞には「いち、さん、ろく」のごとき二字のものと「に、ご」のごとく一字のものがある。数を数える時、こうした不整合が邪魔になる。そこで人は誰でも自然に「にーい、ごーお」というように一文字数詞には母音を足して発音する。...中略... すなわち「に＋ぽん」、「ご＋ぽん」のケースでは、前章に説いたように歴史的に不安定だった /p/ 音を支えてくれる音韻環境がなかった。脆弱な /p/ 音は響きの強く長い母音に前後を囲まれ、その結果「唇音退化」は順調に進行して、もともとの両唇破裂音が摩擦音に変化し、さらには唇のすぼめが弱まって（唇音退化）、けっか声門摩擦音におさまる。そして「にほん、ごほん」という発音に帰着することになる。

Then, the author explains when you are counting 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ..., you pronouncing like 「いち、に(~)い、さん、しい、ご(~)お」to adjust the length of the sound with 2 letters of other numerals. As the sound of 「p」is weak comparing to the vowels of 「に(~)い」and 「ご(~)お」,then Labial weakening progressed. The sound of「p」becoming 「h」, it has become being pronounced as 「にほん」, 「ごほん」.

**For 1, 6 and 8. 一本{いっぽん}, 六本{ろっぽん}, 八本{はっぽん}**

> 「いっぽん、ろっぽん、はっぽん」は「いち、ろく、はち」が連語成分となるために、元来入声［（にっしょう）：この入声については後述］であった語末子音に日本語特有の事情で添加されていた語末母音の脱落がおこる。...中略...「っ」の一字は音楽の休符の役割に近い。音を出さずに次の音を待つのである。この「無音のタメ」には思わぬ副作用があり、これが古い音韻の両唇破裂音——すなわち「ポン」の音を維持する条件になっていたのである。

Regarding「いっぽん、ろっぽん、はっぽん」, 「いち、ろく、はち」being the element of the collocation, the word ending consonant originally which had been the checked tone and the word ending vowel dropped off. Thus, the 「p」has preserved as the dropped checked tone replaced with the gemination 「っ」. The [syncope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syncope_(phonology)) allows you to pronounce voiceless bilabial stop easily.

**For 3,三本{さんぼん}**

> 平たく言えば前後の音が同化する、ということであり /san/ + /pon/ で前者の /n/ が後者の /p/ に同化して両唇性を獲得し /sam/ となる。かたや後者の /p/ は前者の /n/ の有音性に同化して /bon/ となる。あわせて /sambon/ という音韻が獲得される。

/san/ + /pon/ ; the former "n"  regressively being assimilated with "p", it becomes /sam/ with bilabial nasal "m". And, the latter "p" being assimilated with the voiced sound of the former "n", it becomes /bon/. Putting them together, the phoneme of /sambon/ has appeared.

**For, 4,7 and 9.四本{よんほん}, 七本{ななほん}, 九本{きゅうほん}**

> 「し」は平安時代から続く根強い忌み言葉であり、たとえば室町時代の『祇園会御見物御成記』献立表に「二、三、よ、五」とあるという。あからさまに「四（し）」を避けている。...中略...「忌み言葉として『し』は嫌われ四は読みの『よ』を使う」としている。

Due to the tetraphobia of 「し」, 「し」was disliked and 『よ』was used.

> 「きゅうほん」の成立は前章「よんほん、ななほん」同様に新しいと見られる。古来の「く」に代わって「きゅう」は、前段に説いた「し→よん」「しち→なな」の数詞整理と同時期に「九」のスタンダードな読みという立場を確立する。

So, 「きゅう」 replaced with 「く」, the same as numeral adjustment of「し→よん」「しち→なな」occurred in 20th century.

**For 10.十本{じっぼん}**

> 「じっぽん」の形は先にも触れた「促音便に伴う古音の保存」で説明には足りよう。問題は何故に「じゅうほん」がないのか、ということである。しかしこれは実は「偽の問題」であって、「じゅう」という読みそのものが起源的なものではない。むしろ「じっ」という慣用的な促音便の方が、漢数字「十」の起源的な発音の痕跡をありありと残すものである。...中略... さて、「十」の古形推定形に見る -p が入声であり、こうした語彙を古代日本語が取り込む時にはどうしても無理を通さざるを得なくなる。なにしろ日本語は開音節オンリーの言語である。語末閉音節の語形や表記法（さらには感受性）がないのに、この入声の語末音節内破音をなんとか表現しなければならない。そこで「ジフ」などと訓じてお茶を濁した。

「じっぽん」 :  The Gemination preserved the「ぽん」. 十 used to be the checked tone 「p」. However, Japanese language had only open syllable. Therefore, read「ジフ」as kun-yomi to solve the issue.